# Check which bitcoind version I am running

Tags: bitcoind

I have a version of bitcoind on my server and I can't remember which version it is.

How can I find out what version my bitcoind is ?

eg: `./bitcoind -version` ..or such

Comment: What os is the server running?  For example with linux if you installed with apt you can try something like `dpkg -p bitcoind`

Comment: It's running ubuntu 12.04 but the bitcoind was installed from the sourceforge site not the ubuntu apt package manager..

Comment: If it was installed more than 4 days ago (sep 4 2013$ then it's definitely **not** the latest ;) but it looks like thepiachu's answer should clear things up.   Run it as a server then send it getinfo.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

EDIT: As of 0.16.0, use `getnetworkinfo` to get the version of bitcoind:

- getnetworkinfo: version, protocolversion, timeoffset, connections, proxy, relayfee, warnings

Send a `getinfo` [command](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list) to the server. It shows the version of bitcoind:

```
{
  "version": 80400,
  "protocolversion": 70001,
  "walletversion": 60000,
  "balance": 102.2899977,
  "blocks": 104358,
  "timeoffset": 1,
  "connections": 15,
  "proxy": "",
  "difficulty": 1.0,
  "testnet": true,
  "keypoololdest": 1372886245,
  "keypoolsize": 101,
  "paytxfee": 0.0,
  "errors": ""
}
```

Comment: How does `version: 80400` relate to the Bitcoin Core version? I'm trying to check if my bitcoind is running version 0.9.1 of the core.

Comment: It should be `90100`. I guess the format is 00.09.01.00 with leading zeros being truncated.

Comment: Yep - chatting with the developer of [bitcoin-testnet-box](https://github.com/freewil/bitcoin-testnet-box) it's running quite an old version of bitcoind.  I'll look at updating it this weekend.

Comment: This answer is no longer valid as `getinfo` is deprecated as of 0.16.0. Use `getnetworkinfo` instead.

Answer (score 6):

Please consider using `getnetworkinfo` info instead of getinfo since bitcoin 0.16.0

**`bitcoin-cli getnetworkinfo`**

```
{
  "version": 160000,
  "subversion": "/Satoshi:0.16.0/",
  "protocolversion": 70015,
  "localservices": "000000000000040d",
  "localrelay": true,
  "timeoffset": 0,
  "networkactive": true,
  "connections": 5,
  "networks": [
    {
      "name": "ipv4",
      "limited": false,
      "reachable": true,
      "proxy": "",
      "proxy_randomize_credentials": false
    },
    {
      "name": "ipv6",
      "limited": false,
      "reachable": true,
      "proxy": "",
      "proxy_randomize_credentials": false
    },
    {
      "name": "onion",
      "limited": true,
      "reachable": false,
      "proxy": "",
      "proxy_randomize_credentials": false
    }
  ],
  "relayfee": 0.00001000,
  "incrementalfee": 0.00001000,
  "localaddresses": [
  ],
  "warnings": "Warning: unknown new rules activated (versionbit 28)"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Like GetInfo, the [GetNetworkInfo](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#getnetworkinfo) RPC call provides:

- version: The numeric Bitcoin Core (bitcoind) server software version (e.g. 100000)
- protocolversion: The numeric Bitcoin protocol version of the software (e.g. 70002)

In addition, GetNetworkInfo provides the "subversion" user agent string (e.g "/Satoshi:0.10.0/").

Note that the GetInfo call has been deprecated and may be removed in a future version of the software ([source](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#getinfo)).

Answer (score 1):

curl code for achieve that (using [JSON-RPC](http://jsonrpcphp.org/))

```
curl --user YOUR_USER --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "getinfo", "params": [] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:8332/
```

Then it will prompt

```
Enter host password for user 'YOUR_USER':
```

Finally just hit your password and get the bitcoin server response

```
{"result":{"version":666,"protocolversion":666,"walletversion":666,"balance":0.00000000,"blocks":366666,"timeoffset":-9,"connections":8,"proxy":"","difficulty":72722780642.54718018,"testnet":false,"keypoololdest":1448366656,"keypoolsize":666,"paytxfee":0.00000000,"relayfee":0.00001000,"errors":"Warning: Message"},"error":null,"id":"curltest"}
```

You will see something like after running the command-line above where version is what you want to see

**NOTE:**

I'm http://127.0.0.1:8332 that means you have to

```
ssh your_bitcoin_server
```

And also you must have your ~/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf or /etc/bitcoin/bitcoin.conf (as a service) configuration file set to default port (8332)

Feel free to change this as required

Answer (score 0):

If you do not like reading json output, get the `jq` command do it for you

```
bitcoin-cli getnetworkinfo | jq .version
```