# Can I remove the initial bitcoin folder after installing its binaries to /usr/local/bin?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-qt-setup

I know this's kinda a noob question, but I really want to be sure I'm not making a mistake.

I want to install Bitcoin Core GUI on my Linux by the following steps:

1. Download `bitcoin-0.20.1-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz` into the Downloads folder
2. Extract it `tar xzf bitcoin-0.20.1-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz`
3. Copy binaries into the */usr/local/bin*: `sudo install -m 0755 -o root -g root -t /usr/local/bin ~/Downloads/bitcoin-0.20.1/bin/*`

Each step is exact the same as described here: https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#linux-instructions

**The question is:** Can I now remove the extracted `~/Downloads/bitcoin-0.20.1` folder after installing the contents of its *bin* subdirectory into the */usr/local/bin*?

Is it enough to have only binaries into the */usr/local/bin* to run the program?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, after you've checked if bitcoin is properly ["installed"](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/13165/check-which-bitcoind-version-i-am-running) by checking its version you can remove the `~/Downloads/bitcoin-0.20.1`. Be sure to double-check the processes and be careful before putting funds in without backup.